# QT 4.8 crash at ordinary comparison

Tags: c++, qt, crash

Please help me explain unexpected crash!!!
I have:

> x.h

```
class x: QObject
   struct
    {
        struct
        {
            struct
            {
                int state;
                double curstring;
                QTimer timer_scroll;
                QTimer timer_done;
            }color;
            struct
            {
                int state;
                double curstring;
                QTimer timer_scroll;
                QTimer timer_done;
            }mono;
        }S2L_NOTIFY;
```

....etc

> x.cpp

```
void x::draw(const int type, QString str, bool isNeedAnswer)
{
    if(type == 3)
    {
        //here is crash!
        if(bitmap.S2L_NOTIFY.mono.state == 3 &&  bitmap.S2L_NOTIFY.color.state == 3)
        {
```

`if((bitmap.S2L_NOTIFY.mono.state == 3))` -< not crash here

`if((bitmap.S2L_NOTIFY.color.state == 3))`   -< not crash here

Please tell me where am i wrong or compilator wrong?

Comment: Can you run your program under `valgrind` or some other debugger?

Comment: you should have at least posted a code that compiles.. What you have provided is foobar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have x in your condition, but the function `x::rndfunc()` is a member function of class x... not a variable. It should be:

```
// "this" refers to the current instance of class x
if((this->y.z.f.nmb2 == NOTOK) && (this->y.z.f.nmb1 == NOTOK))
```

or simply:

```
// but the "this" isn't actually necessary
if((y.z.f.nmb2 == NOTOK) && (y.z.f.nmb1 == NOTOK))
```

(as you wrote).

**EDIT:** Okay, so there was a typo in the original question, so the above is no longer relevant. The new answer is:

`f` does not have a member variable `nmb1`, only `nmb2`.

**EDIT #2:** More typos. My new answer:

What you're trying to do looks really messy. Don't do it.

Comment: if((this->y.z.f.nmb2 == NOTOK) && (this->y.z.f.nmb1 == NOTOK))
It was my TYPO, programm still doesnot work.

Comment: @HARD well then isn't the problem that nmb1 is not a member variable of f (but rather of h)?

Comment: It was debug mode bug! So i tried to debug other my bug in debug mode, and this comparison bug stoped me.

p.s. debug mode bug?! LoL

Comment: Well, glad you figured it out!